# Reverse geocode using geopy - x and y into adresses, reading csv,

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding, geopy

I have a csv file with 3 columns - id, ax and ay. I want the program to take ax and ay data from a csv sheet and convert it to addresses and save it to another .csv file.

I do a code but it don't working. Thanks for help.

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
import csv


df = pd.read_csv('punkty_xy.csv')
id2 = df['id']
x = df['ax']
y = df['ay']
location = geolocator.geocode(f"{x}, {y}")
geo_loc = location.raw


with open('output.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['ID', 'cordX', 'cordY', 'Adresses']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if not file_exists:
        writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'ID': id2, 'cordX': x, 'cordY': y, 'Adresses': geo_loc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


# Geocoding
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeolocator")
location = geolocator.geocode("225 Baker St NW, Atlanta, GA 30313, United States")
location.raw

# Reverse Geocoding
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeolocator")
location = geolocator.reverse("33.76326745, -84.39511726814364")

print("latitude:", location.latitude)
print("longitude:", location.longitude)

latitude: 33.76326745
longitude: -84.39511726814364
location.raw


# Read from Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path_here\\test.csv')
df.dtypes

lats=df['pickup_latitude'].to_list()
lons=df['pickup_longitude'].to_list()
# Creating a zip with latitudes and longitudes
coords=list(zip(lats,lons))

full_address=[]
for i in range(len(coords)):
    location = geolocator.reverse(coords[i])
    print(location)
    full_address.append(location)
    
address=pd.DataFrame(data=full_address)
address
```